# Why is value initialization so named?

Tags: c++, initialization, value-initialization

It's really unclear to me why anyone would name a particular form of initialization "value initialization". It sounds as though it's initializing the object by giving it a value... but that's what initialization does in general, and the name doesn't tell you anything about *which* value it's going to use for the initialization.

Comment: The term appears to be first proposed in [N1191](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1999/n1191.pdf).

Comment: Perhaps it was the fact that it actually *does* always give some sensible value. Default initialization often doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Boost value_init write-up](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm) provide a rather detailed history of *value initialization* it ended up in the standard from [defect report 178: More on value-initialization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#178)  and it seems like the term originated from [defect report 35: Definition of default-initialization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#35). Although none of these documents really provide a proper origin for the term it does provide some good ideas, it says:

> The first Technical Corrigendum for the C++ Standard (TC1), whose
>   draft was released to the public in November 2001, introduced Core
>   Issue 178 (among many other issues, of course).
>
> That issue introduced the new concept of value-initialization (it also
>   fixed the wording for zero-initialization). Informally,
>   value-initialization is similar to default-initialization with the
>   exception that in some cases non-static data members and base class
>   sub-objects are also value-initialized. **The difference is that an
>   object that is value-initialized won't have (or at least is less
>   likely to have) indeterminate values for data members and base class
>   sub-objects; unlike the case of an object default constructed. (see
>   Core Issue 178 for a normative description).**
>
> In order to specify value-initialization of an object we need to use
>   the empty-set initializer: ().

and value initialization is less likely to leave an object with an indeterminate value versus *default-initalization*.

Comment: OT, but this change introduced an annoying problem; for a POD struct `T foo = T();` and similar such statements was only guaranteed to "work" in C++03, so in portable code you couldn't do it without risking that it'd be run on a C++98 compiler and silently cause dreadful UB.

Comment: @MattMcNabb that is unfortunate, is there a defect report for that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, it was just a new thing added in TC1